# PHP--How do I put form information into an HTML table once it has been saved to a text file?

Tags: php, html

This is just a block of code I am struggling with. Not sure if I am correct while trying to get this to format into an HTML table. I've messed with this for the last two hours trying to get it to work, I still don't have a clue what I am doing wrong. I am trying to get the information that comes from my array posted into the HTML table.

```
$ExistingSig = array('Name'=>'1','Version'=>'2','Hardware'=>'3', 'System'=>'4', 'Frequency'=>'5', 'Solution'=>'6');                     
$Report = array('Name'=>'a','Version'=>'b','Hardware'=>'c', 'System'=>'d', 'Frequency'=>'e', 'Solution'=>'f');

echo "<table border='1'>";

$count1=0;
foreach ($ExistingSig as $key => $value)
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  if(!is_array($value))     
   {
       if($key == 'Name' or $key == 'Version' or $key == 'Hardware' or $key == 'System' or $key == 'Frequency' or $key == 'Solution')
    {
        echo "<td>";
        echo  $key . ':' . $value;
        echo "<br />\n";
        echo "</td>";
    }
   }

  $count2=0;
   foreach ($ExistingSig as $key => $value)
    {
   if($count1==$count2){
     //to eliminate array to string conversion error 
     if(!is_array($value))     
     {
         if($key == '$AddName' or $key == '$AddVer' or $key == '$AddHard' or $key == '$AddSys' or $key == '$AddFreq' or $key == '$AddSol')
         {
             echo "<td>";
             echo  $key . ':' . $value;
             echo "<br />\n";
             echo "</td>";
         }
     }
      }
      $count2++;
   }
    echo "</tr>";
      $count1++;
  }
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: What's the expected result? What the actual output? Please read [how do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: @CarriesBack, Can you please brief what output you want ? Please edit the question again

Comment: I am just trying to get the information in that is posted into the array from my form into the table

Comment: This is definitely not what @gp_sflover asked you - _What's the **expected result**? What the **actual output**?_ Read the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) they provided in order to get good answers on SO instead of downvotes that will eventually lead to a question ban

Comment: I am doing a report form that each field is put into an array, the array information is then posted to a table on the same web page.

Comment: @CarriesBack It might help us if you could post what you want the table to look like. It's not clear here what sort of table you are expecting. You could mock one up in Word, for example, and just post a screenshot.

Comment: just a basic table with a 1px border, nothing fancy just something to show the output. The headers are Name, Version, Hardware, System, Frequency and Solutions

Comment: @CarriesBack so does that mean that after the headers, there's one row that's 1 | 2 | 3 etc and another row thats a | b | c etc? A header and 2 rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this works for you

```
<?php

$ExistingSig = array('Name'=>'1','Version'=>'2','Hardware'=>'3', 'System'=>'4', 'Frequency'=>'5', 'Solution'=>'6');                     
$Report = array('Name'=>'a','Version'=>'b','Hardware'=>'c', 'System'=>'d', 'Frequency'=>'e', 'Solution'=>'f');


$wantedKeys = array('Name','Version','Hardware','System','Frequency', 'Solution');

$thead = "<thead>";
$tbody="<tbody>";
    foreach ($ExistingSig as $key => $value){
        if(in_array($key,$wantedKeys)){
            $thead .= "<th>$key</th>";
            $tbody .= "<td>$value</td>";
        }
    }

echo "<table border='1'>$thead</thead>$tbody</tbody></table>";
?>
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much

Comment: if this answers your question please mark it as answer

Comment: I do not see where I do that